# log installed files when compiling

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, linux-from-scratch

im currently building LFS and looking for a package management solution

specifically a program that keeps track of what files got installed when you compiled
something from source also has a method for removing those files in case make uninstall isnt present

i have looked into programs like [`install-log`](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/PREVIOUS_FORMAT/installwatch.txt) and [`checkinstall`](https://asic-linux.com.mx/%7Eizto/checkinstall/index.php) but couldnt get both to compile

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I have always used the **User Based Management** (aka "Package Users"), as described in section [8.2. Package Management](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/pkgmgt.html). It doesn't get much love, even from the LFS community, despite it (still) being in the book and being the only method "unique to LFS".

It's not great for the first timer as it will really force you to dig deep at times to solve issues and make important decisions. I suggest you complete your first LFS system build, then consider Package Users your next time around.

But once you get used to it, it works great.

Another, simpler, method is the **Timestamp Based** technique (described in the same link).

For example, when it comes time to copy a package's files to your system, you can do something like this:

```
touch timestamp_start
    
make install
    
# do other stuff as instructed
    
touch timestamp_stop

find / -newer timestamp_start -not -newer timestamp_stop > list_of_files_affected
```

And I do use this approach when installing the Nvidia proprietary drivers, because successfully installing them with a non-root account is a real pain.

Comment: thanks! it works just as intended, its strange that no find programs are made for logging files in general