# log and monitor files created

Tags: linux, unix, logging

is there a program to log and monitor files created?

the purpose is that if i run `<theProgramForLogging> foo/bar/baz.o` i get some context of the file like the process/user that made it, like if i run `make install` to compile a program, it logs the installed files and marks them that they are file from `x` program when it was compiled

i had asked this in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71834674/18567143) but this time the question is more general for logging not just for compiling and perhaps more automated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
stat <filename>
```

Will give you some information about a file. If you run the file as a program, you can find the pid and what started it by

```
pstree
```

Comment: How does that actualy _monitor_ the changes in the directory structure?